# Change the Cell.TextLabel Width in IOS Sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the `width for the cell TextLabel` because it overlap the my custom buttons.

I try the following code but it removes the cell separation line.

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect textLabelFrame = self.textLabel.frame;

    textLabelFrame.size.width=250.0f;
    self.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
}
```

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding  [super layoutSubviews] at the start of your layoutSubviews ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `[super layoutSubviews]` at the start of your layoutSubviews.  You won't get the default behaviors of your class, such as the cell separation line otherwise.